# PHP5 Socket Server Flash

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, serversocket

I am trying to get a rather simple flash game to work with a php socket. As of right now, I'm running a test with the socket which just allows users to chat with eachother. This WILL run on my personal machine, only from the IDE. If I try and run the SWF or the .html, no go. I know people are on the border for using PhP vs C# vs C++ vs HTML, ect ect but I really want to stick with php since the hosting that I am using will support this, and eventually I will get experienced enough to go deeper into the socket server.

So my problem is that I have it working *mostly* . If I test it in Flash CS5 (Ctrl+Enter) it will run the traces and everything and stop when it can not connect, which I expected. However, when I go to run it from the SWF, or the HTML, then it wont even initialize. The code below will make this a bit more clear

```
import flash.net.*;
import fl.controls.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.DataEvent;
import flash.events.SecurityErrorEvent;

var mySocket = new XMLSocket();
pushMsg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, realsedButton);
//mySocket.connect("192.124.5.2",9999);
mySocket.addEventListener(Event.CONNECT, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, xmlsocket);
mySocket.addEventListener(DataEvent.DATA, dataHandler);
mySocket.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityHandler);   

msgArea.htmlText = "Started!";
connectToServer();
function connectToServer()
{
    msgArea.htmlText = "Inside connect To Server";
    mySocket.connect("localhost",9999);
}

function securityHandler(evt: SecurityErrorEvent)
{
    msgArea.htmlText = "SecurityError";
}

function dataHandler(evt:DataEvent)
{
    trace("Inside dataHandler")
    var xml = XML(evt.target.data);
    msgArea.htmlText += xml;
}


function xmlsocket(Event)
{
    msgArea.htmlText += "inside xmlSocket";
    switch(Event.type)
    {
        case 'ioError':
            msgArea.htmlText += "Inside dataHandler";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection failed!</b>";
            break;

        case 'connect':
            msgArea.htmlText +="Inside Connect";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection establed!</b>";
            break;

        case 'close':
            msgArea.htmlText +="Inside Close";
            msgArea.htmlText += "<b>Server connection lost</b>";
            break;
    }
}
function msgGO() 
{
    msgArea.htmlText +="Inside msgGO";
    if (inputMsg.htmlText != "") 
    {
        msgArea.htmlText +="Inside msgGo2";
        mySocket.send(inputMsg.htmlText+"\n");
        inputMsg.htmlText = "";
    }
}

function realsedButton(evt:MouseEvent)
{
    msgArea.htmlText +="Inside ReleasedButton";
    msgGO();
}
```

So When I run this from the IDE it outputs: 
Inside connect To Server
inside xmlSocket
Inside dataHandler
Server connection failed!

Which is good, other than it is skipping the Started! (unsure why)

When I run this from the SWF or HTML 
Inside connect To Server

That is all that happens. I added in the messages to trace exactly where the code is jumping when. In my publish settings, I do have it set to Use Network Files, I have also tried Use Local Files.

Using Network Files, the SWF will output
Inside connect To Server

Using Local Files, it will not output anything.

If anyone could explain this or help me out I would greatly appreciate it.

Okay, so we have made some small progress. It will now run on the machine, Giving us the Started! Inside connect To Server, and then the Security Error pops about 10-15 seconds later.

We are running this on 9999 but I had heard there was somethign icky about port 843 and security errors, any way to debug this error? We ONLY get it when we are trying to run it from the actual server using the PhP Socket.

If I run the swf on my personal Machine, I still do not get passed the Started! and Inside connect To Server no matter how long I wait

Comment: The reason it's skipping the "Started!" is because in `msgArea.htmlText = "Inside connect To Server";`, you're using `=` rather than `+=`.

Comment: Ahhh hehe well thank you for that catch! :)

Comment: Are you testing between two machines or on the same?

Comment: Right now, the same machine

Answer (score 0):

Reason of firing `SecurityError` event is a there is no `crossdomain file` on port `843`. Flash Player trying connect to 843 port and requesting crossdomain file. But FP firing `SecurityError` if this file not exist, or not correct.